# Conversão de código Java para C#

Tags: java, c#, conversão

Eu gostaria de uma ajuda para converter o seguinte código em Java para C#.

```
public static long convertStringToBitboard(String Binary) 
{
    if (Binary.charAt(0)=='0') 
    {
        return Long.parseLong(Binary, 2);
    } else 
    {
        return Long.parseLong("1"+Binary.substring(2), 2)*2;
    }
}
```

Tentei utilizar ferramentas que realizam a tradução automática, mas não obtive exito. Pesquisando pelo Google também não consegui fazer.

A dúvida mesmo são as linhas

```
return Long.parseLong(Binary, 2);
return Long.parseLong("1"+Binary.substring(2), 2)*2;
```

Aguardo uma ajuda. Eu pra falar a verdade já perdi a esperança de fazer isso funcionar em C#, espero que consiga com a ajuda de vocês :)

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A única coisa que muda é que o método para converter uma *string* para um inteiro de 64 bits é o `Convert.ToInt64` ao invés de `Long.parseLong`.

Note também que a [convenção de escrita de código C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) diz que os métodos devem ser escritos em PascalCase e que os parâmetros devem ser escritos em camelCase (neste caso é igual à convenção do Java).

Tanto Java quanto em C# o código poderia ser escrito de uma maneira mais curta.

```
public static long ConvertStringToBitboard(string binary) 
{
    return binary[0] == '0' ? Convert.ToInt64(binary, 2) : Convert.ToInt64("1" + binary.Substring(2), 2) * 2;
}
```

Nas versões mais modernas do C# (6+) é possível escrever em forma de *expression body* e usar interpolação de *string*.

```
public static long convertStringToBitboard(string binary) => 
    binary[0] == '0' ? Convert.ToInt64(binary, 2) : Convert.ToInt64($"1{binary.Substring(2)}", 2) * 2;
```

Comment: Eu posso ao menos saber o motivo do voto contra?

Comment: Muito obrigado LINQ. Sou novo aqui. Estou marcando a pergunta como solucionada. Bem... não foi eu que negativei. Mais uma vez muito obrigado.